# Almost surely convergence of series

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $\{Y_t\}_{t=1}^\infty$ be a time series with $\mathbb{E}|Y|<\infty$ and $\sum_{j=0}^\infty |a_j|<\infty$, prove $X_t=\sum_{j=0}^\infty a_jY_{t-j}$ converges almost surely.

The following is my proof. Is it correct?

Define partial sum $S_N=\sum_{j=0}^N a_jY_{t-j}$, by the Cauchy criterion, $S_N$ converges almost surely if for any $\varepsilon>0$, exists positive integer $N$ such that for all $k, l\geq N$,
$$\mathbb{P}[\inf_N\sup_{k,l\geq N}|S_k-S_l|<\varepsilon]=1$$
Then let event $A_\varepsilon$ be this, and the complement of $A_\varepsilon$ is
\begin{align*}
A_\varepsilon^c&=\bigcap_{N=1}^\infty\left\{\sup_{k, l\geq N}\left|\sum_{i=l+1}^{k}a_iY_{t-i}\right|\geq\varepsilon \right\} \\
  &=\bigcap_{N=1}^\infty\bigcup_{k, l\geq N}\left\{\left|\sum_{i=l+1}^{k}a_iY_{t-i}\right|\geq\varepsilon\right\}
\end{align*}
Define event $A_{k, l}=\left\{\left|\sum_{i=l+1}^{k}a_iY_{t-i}\right|\geq\varepsilon\right\}$. Note that
\begin{align*}
  \sum_{k,l\geq N}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}[A_{k,l}]\leq \sum_{k,l\geq N}^{\infty}\varepsilon^{-1}\mathbb{E}\left|\sum_{i=l+1}^{k}a_iY_{t-i}\right|\leq \sum_{k,l\geq N}^{\infty}\sum_{i=l+1}^{k}\varepsilon^{-1}|a_i|\mathbb{E}|Y_{t-i}|
  \end{align*}
The first inequality is Markov's inequality and the following is triangle inequality. Because of $\mathbb{E}|Y|<\infty$ and $\sum_{j=0}^\infty|a_j|<\infty$, we get $\mathbb{P}[A_{k,l}]<\infty$. By the Borel-Cantelli first lemma, finally we conclude $\mathbb{P}[A_\varepsilon^c]=0$.